# Remove Android Toolbar Navigation Drawer option

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

How can i remove the leftmost navigation drawer menu item on the Android Toolbar. Basically i wan't to contain 4 images in a horizontal fashion, Nothing else !

Comment: None of answers working

Answer (score 10):

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

This should remove the navigation drawer icon

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
yourActionBarDrawer.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

This will remove the hamburger icon on toolbar completely.

Answer (score 8):

My solution:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.ACCEPT, R.string.CANCEL);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

Might be late but you can get the reference to the Toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.yourToolbarId);
```

then

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

Reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

> Parameters icon
>   Drawable to set, may be null to clear the icon

**EDIT:** if the title doesn't look aligned call:

```
toolbar.getMenu().clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the totally unfashionable margin who have the toolbar in the left side for a posible navigation icon you should do:

```
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Comment: this unswer helps me when i am using  fragment with AppBarLayout and Toolbar in it

Answer (score 0):

```
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null)
    {
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
```