# Hide Navigation Drawer in certain Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-navigation

I build an app which has a login screen and the home screen. I am following the single activity design principle. I have implemented the Navigation drawer like this.
This is my `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,drawerLayout)
}
}
```

MainAcivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navdrawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I also have two fragments `loginFrament` and `homeFragment`
now the navigation drawer is shown both of this fragment but I want it to be in the Home Screen fragment only.
checked some resources [how to hide navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432973/how-to-hide-navigation-drawer-when-opening-certain-fragment). but this method only lock the drawer.

Comment: How do you navigate to loginFragment?

Comment: I am navigating using the navigation Graph, I am using the navigation design pattern from jetpacks @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0):

I've same design app and i made login/register screens with activity and all other screens which i want to navigte with nav drawer made with fragments, also in some submenus which i don't want to show drawer, i used activity again. Activity & fragments works pretty good together. Navigating without drawer between activities looks more easier to me tbh. Happy codin!