# How to hide a navigation drawer icon in start destination fragment and show it next to start destination fragment for navigation graph

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I would develop an android app with Single Activity and Two Fragments (LoginFragment and HomeFragment) with Navigation Drawer using Navigation Graph.

When I had add a `Navigationdrawer` in my activity it is visible in `LoginFragment` but I want to display hamburger icon only in `HomeFragment` not `LoginFragment`.

How to add a navigation drawer in activity without add it to `LoginFragment`

I had tried to hide a `toolbar`

```
        val navController=this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{ nc: NavController, nd: NavDestination, _->
            if(nd.id==nc.graph.startDestination){
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
                binding.toolBar.visibility = View.GONE

            }else{
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
                NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,drawerLayout)
                binding.toolBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
```

I want to display hamburger icon only in `HomeFragment` not `LoginFragment`

Comment: Sir@Meenakshi Sundaram how you solved this problem?I had the same

Comment: There's a popular answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433150 . If that doesn't work for you, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003163 .

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using Kotlin. But I don't think it will be different from the method in Java. You can convert from Java to Kotlin. That's what I did in java.

```
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide(); // to hide toolbar
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show(); //to show toolbar
```

You need use this codes in fragments. For example you can set ...hide(); method in onCreateView method of LoginFragment, after that you can set ...show(); method in oncreateView of HomeFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions for hide and show navigation drawer icon in your activity and call these functions in your respective fragments onCreateView